# Firebase is uploading & fetching data on another app server

Tags: flutter, firebase

I was working on 2 projects at a time. Everything was working fine but when I uploaded my data from my app to the firestore, it was not found in the firestore. After checking it I found that it is uploading my data to my another firebase app database. Please help me resolving the issue I cannot find the error. It was working fine before, now both the apps are crashing.

Comment: My best guess is that you may have mixed up your `firebase_options.dart` file (or the native `.json` and `.plist` files with the same information), but it's going to be really hard to say anything more concretely without seeing some sort of [minimal repro](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My best guess is that you switched up the files that contain the information on how to connect to Firebase between these projects.

- If you recently created these apps, that data is likely in a `firebase_options.dart` file that was created by the `flutterfire` CLI command.
- But otherwise the information may also be stored in a `google-services.json` file for Android, and a `GoogleService-Info.plist` file for iOS.

Whichever of these it is, you'll want to check the data in these files and update them to refer to the correct Firebase project for each app.